# drawRect line moves on different screen size

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawrect

I'm using `drawRect` to create a **line**. Based on the "4inch screen" my line is the correct place. When ran on a "3.5 inch screen" the line is lower down and in the wrong place.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef firstLine = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextMoveToPoint(firstLine, 15, 389);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(firstLine, 320, 389);
    CGContextStrokePath(firstLine);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(firstLine, 1.1);
}
```

I know I need to do something with `self.frame.heigh` to make it dynamic to screen size but don't know where to put it.

Comment: Your code is already not working: `CGContextStrokePath(firstLine); CGContextSetLineWidth(firstLine, 1.1);` You cannot set the line width _after_ you have drawn. Also it is pointless to set line width to a funny fractional amount like that, since there are no fractional pixels on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Get the height of the view bounds each time you draw it and you are good to go.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
   /* Get the height of the view */
    float height = CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds);
  /* the amount to inset the line by */
    float lineInset = 20;
 /* y-position after insetting the line */
    float yPosition = height - lineInset;
    CGContextRef firstLine = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextMoveToPoint(firstLine, 15, yPosition);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(firstLine, 320, yPosition);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(firstLine, 1.1);
    CGContextStrokePath(firstLine);
}
```

Comment: Very insightful and helpful answer! - You have accidentally created a float `lineInset` that you never use; you should fix that. Note also my comment to his question: do not repeat his mistake of calling `CGContextSetLineWidth` after drawing where it has no effect.

Comment: Oh, one more thing - you should also explain the OP _why_ your answer works where his code doesn't. (It's because the height of the view whose `drawRect` this is differs on 4-inch vs. 3.5-inch screen.)

Comment: @matt Thank you very much. I didn't notice that I was not using the lineInset variable and that he was setting the linewidth after drawing it. I corrected it.